# Логирование абстрактных типов используя значения конкретных типов в C#

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, логирование

Есть сервис, читающий сообщения из очереди. Необходимо реализовать логирование некоторых полей приходящих сообщений. Сообщения - разных типов с разным набором полей. Как это выглядит прямо сейчас:

Есть интерфейс IMessage, у которого нет ни свойств, ни методов.

Есть реализации IMessage (названия полей и классов - не настоящие, созданы только для демонстрации примера).

1. AlertMessage

   ```
   public class AlertMessage: IMessage
   {
       public string AlertHeader { get;set; }
       public string AlertId { get;set; }
       // Здесь еще много других полей
   }
   ```
2. StatusMessage

   ```
   public class StatusMessage: IMessage
   {
       public string StatusId { get;set; }
       public double Speed { get; set; }
       // Здесь еще много других полей
   }
   ```

Код обработки сообщений:

```
public async Task ReceiveAndProcessMessagesAsync()
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<IMessage> messages;

    do
    {
        messages = await _receiveService.ReceiveMessagesAsync();

        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            try
            {
                var messageProcessor = GetMessageProcessor(message);
                await messageProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error during processing.");
            }
            finally
            {
                await message.MarkAsProcessedAsync();
                if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("Message processed. {MessageType}. {@Message}", message.GetType().Name, message);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Message processed. {MessageType}", message.GetType());
                }
            }
        }
    } while (messages.Count > 0);
}

private IMessageProcessor GetMessageProcessor(IMessage message)
{
    return message switch
    {
        AlertMessage alertMessage => new AlertMessageProcessor(alertMessage),
        StatusMessage statusMessage => new StatusMessageProcessor(statusMessage),
        //...
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown message.")
    };
}
```

Мне нужно в блоке finally в строке:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Message processed. {MessageType}", message.GetType());
```

дополнительно логировать поля сообщений. Т.е. чтобы

1. для AlertMessage было сообщение

> Message processed. {MessageType}, AlertId = {AlertId}, AlertHeader = {AlertHeader}

2. для StatusMessage было сообщение

> Message processed. {MessageType}, StatusId = {StatusId}, Speed = {Speed}

Как можно реализовать такое поведение? Пытаюсь найти каноническое решение в интернете, но не знаю, как правильно загуглить. Можно сделать метод типа `LogMessageProcessed(IMessage message)`, там сделать такой же switch-case, что и в `GetMessageProcessor(IMessage message)`, и в зависимости от типа логировать по-разному. Это первое, что мне приходит в голову. Еще приходит в голову сделать декоратор для процессоров сообщений с логированием.

Comment: Базовый тип не обязан знать о потомках, так что имху только через рефлексию лезть за доп. полями. Ну либо вносить в интерфейс, чего вы не хотите.

Comment: @AK о том, что я не хочу добавлять в интерфейс доп свойство - я не говорил в вопросе :) Решение ок, но насколько хорошо то, что поле, нужное только для логирования, появится в интерфейсе сообщения? Это мне напоминает метод `ToString()` у объекта

Comment: Конечно нехорошо. Только мне вот что-то странно: что это за поле которое совершенно не нужно ни для чего, кроме логирования? Такое впечатление, что это уникальный идентификатор запроса -- и странно что у сообщения в интерфейсе его нет. Как по мне полноценное поле.

Comment: Переопределите `ToString` у этих сообщений и готово. Этот метод собственно и предназначен для отладки и тому подобных действий. Логирование туда же.

Comment: Интерфейс без членов называют [маркерным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Интерфейс-маркер_(шаблон_проектирования)). В дотнете их использование не рекомендуется (следует заменять на атрибут). Но в данном конкретном случае типы, наследующие этот интерфейс должны иметь некую определённую функциональность: предоставлять свои члены для логирования. Поэтому либо у интерфейса нужно сделать член (свойство или метод), предназначенный для логирования (а-ля `LogMessage()`), либо вместо интерфейса сделать базовый класс (естественно, у него должны быть сделаны возможости логирования).

Comment: @AK сделал через свойство. Да, выглядит так, что эти поля уникально идентифицируют сообщение, поэтому добавил свойство `Identifier` в базовый интерфейс. Не желаете оформить ответ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov согласен с вами. Можно было бы и через ToString. Ваши советы полезны, спасибо. Если желаете, можете оформить свой ответ (я вам поставлю +1), но в случае, если `@AK` оформит ответ, галочкой отмечать буду его вариант.

Comment: Уступаю написание ответа: во-первых, вам виднее классы вашего проекта, во-вторых, вам проще собрать воедино всё существенное из наших комментариев.

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать с помощью рефлексии.

Допустим есть такой класс:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Вот так можно вытянуть свойства:

```
var message = new Message() { Text = "текст", Id = 0 }; // пример объекта

var propertiesText = message
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public) // выбираете нужные поля
    .Select(property => property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(message))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", propertiesText));
```

Вывод: `Text = текст, Id = 0`

Ну и это всё конечно можно свернуть в метод или метод-расширение и потом легко использовать:

```
public static string GetPropertiesValuesString<T>(this T obj)
{
    var propertiesValues = obj
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public) // выбираете нужные поля
        .Select(property => property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(obj))
        .ToList();

    return string.Join(", ", propertiesValues);
}
```

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но если потребуются не все поля, а лишь конкретные?

Comment: @Blackmeser в таком случае можно просто в метод добавить параметр `params string[] propertiesNames` и после `.GetProperties()` добавить `.Where(property => propertiesNames.Contains(property.Name))`

Comment: @KuzCode к сожалению, мне этот вариант не подходит. Но он имеет место быть

Comment: @AndreiKhotko вам только одно решение подойдёт - свой метод, возвращающий строку на подобии ToString, от интерфейса к наследникам.